# Is it possible to type new Value in PXSelector

Tags: acumatica

I'm using already the `[ValidateValue =false]` in `PXselector` attribute, it works when typing new Value on the selector, but it does not selects to null value if I remove the value in the Selector.
[image]

the highlighted field is the field that can perform Selecting and Typing new Value. However this behavior is approachable using Autonumber Setup and use Manual Input, but that is not what I wanted.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at Shipping Terms page (CS208000), I think the Term ID selector is working exactly in the way you want.

Comment: will take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the Purchase Receipts (PR000803, POReceiptEntry) screen. You can add a Location dynamically in the grid by typing in the new location name and hitting save. This is accomplished through the field LocationID with Attribute IN.LocationAttribute.